# How to create a custom content type with a quiz field?

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I'm pretty much new to Drupal 8, is there a way of creating a custom content type with a quiz field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Field Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_quiz) module. It already has an alpha version for Drupal 8.

According to the module description,

> This module provides a simple field that can be used as a simple quiz
>   or multiple choice questions. It provides a field with a textfield and
>   a checkbox / radio selection combined. If added to any entity
>   (node/content type, user, taxonomy term, ...) the editor of the entity
>   can enter multiple answers in the textfields and determine which
>   answers are correct.
>
> This module is for everybody who does not want to use the whole
>   complex system of the quiz module, but just a simple field for
>   multiple choice questions.

Comment: How do I add the Field Quiz module to the content type?

Comment: In principle, after installing the module, you should be able to add the field it provides to any content type, in the usual way: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/nodes-content-types-and-fields/add-a-field-to-a-content-type (the procedure is almost the same for both Drupal 7 and Drupal 8)